# Hide Facebook page wall posts apart from Statuses

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am pulling in a facebook feed into a website I am devloping. I have got the feed to pull through but unfortunately it shows posts made onto the page by other Facebook users. 
I want the feed to only show wall posts made by the page. Is this possible?

Here is the URL i am using to pull in the feed:

https://graph.facebook.com/HadleighSwimmingPool/feed?access_token=292423037531408|0cc972ba47bcdafed97f3d01a2a3bd77&limit=1

Thanks

Comment: You could try using FQL, read the `stream` table and filter by `actor_id`. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream

Comment: Ok thanks I will use this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe said, you can use [Facebook Query Language](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).

Here's the FQL query you need:

```
SELECT message FROM stream WHERE source_id=[page-id] AND actor_id=[page-id]
```

For testing you can use the [graph api explorer tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20message%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%3D%5bpage-id%5d%20AND%20actor_id%3D%5bpage-id%5d).